# A vertical orientation app with one view controller horizontal orientation. How to design on the storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm currently working on a small iOS camera app and have a storyboard-related question.

[image]

(Sorry for my bad drawing) Here is what I got on my storyboard, I have two view controllers, mainVC and cameraVC, and I added table view cells to mainVC to add a segue to cameraVC. This app is a vertical orientation app, and I want to make this app horizontally only when the user gets to the cameraVC. I'm not planning to make this app rotatable, hence this app only supports the vertical orientation if the user is in MainVC and only supports the horizontal orientation if the user is in CameraVC.

I'd add several more vertical view controllers later on, so I make the app vertical on the storyboard. However, I was not sure how should I design the camera VC on my storyboard.

While the app is running and the user gets to the camera VC, I want the app orientation horizontal (and don't rotate to vertical) and display buttons on the right side, like the image below.
[image]

So my question is while all the view controllers set to vertical, should I place buttons on the cameraVC at the bottom like the first image, or is better to place buttons on the right side with assuming the VC rotates when the user gets the camera VC, like the image below?

[image]

Sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing a view controller in storyboard there is no property for orientation. There are however simulated values that are applied to whole storyboard to be either landscape or portrait.

If you want to simulate these values differently I suggest that you move your camera view controller to another storyboard. I would actually do that regardless of the issue you are facing.

If this doesn't suit you for any reason then you can still simulate your view differently. You can simply select your camera view controller in storyboard and use a Freeform simulated size like on the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: @Oblak Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I think separating storyboard will solve this issue and I will try this today!
Once I finish solving this issue, I'll accept this answer! Again, thank you so much.